# Does C++ (Visual Studio) have Java style comments?

Tags: java, c++

When we use /** */ comment style in Java, it have those annotations @param,
 or @num1, which makes easier to read the comments, and removes the ambiguities who can appear. For example if you want to make a reference in your comment to `num1`, by writing `@num1` the color changes and you know that the comment refers at parameter `num1`, but if you say `num1`, the color of the parameter remains the same and it comes hard to read and may be confused with another variable with the same name. This was just an example.

Java style:

```
/**
 * @param num1
 * @param num2
*/
public void sum(int num1, int num2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: These annotations are for Java doc. You can use similar tool with c/c++. You have to use doxygen and it's syntax.

Comment: are you talking of VS?? then https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177246.aspx

Comment: C++ has no tightly integrated comment processor. Many people use Doxygex for such work,  very good program.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ yes I am talking about VS, good observation !, I edited the title now

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard does not define any comment semantics like Java does with [Javadocs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc).

There are, however, extensions, like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html), [cldoc](http://jessevdk.github.io/cldoc/documenting.html) or [DOC++](http://docpp.sourceforge.net/), which provide similar functionality.

Check if your IDE/text editor supports doxygen syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer !!

Answer (score 6):

It has nothing to do with the language itself but there are documentation generating programs that do understand "Javadoc" style comments.

For example [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer !!

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't come with a processor for those comments, but they do exist. I was using one 13 years ago. I think it was called ... `cppdoc`, but don't quote me.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for this answer, I will check !